# DB2 Scale out for vendor solution

Tags: db2

Currently I'm dealing with a vendor application that uses DB2 Workgroup Server Edition 10.1 on Windows Server 2012 . Right now I'm able to scale up as demand increases, but eventually we will hit a limit in terms of CPU. The application produces dynamic queries that aren't properly optimized. I've spoken with the vendor and there is no short term solution, as any indexes I add myself get removed whenever they update their schema. That being said, could I benefit from active-active replication? I've looked at PureScale, but that seems limited to Linux, but that could possibly be an option. Q Replication with Active-Active seems ideal in terms of latency and throughput. Is there any other option in terms of scale out? Which option would be easiest to implement and which option provides the best performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned only about being able to support more load, you can certainly scale up beyond the CPU limits in Workgroup Server Edition by going to Enterprise Server Edition, which will let you scale up to whatever hardware you can buy.

That said, this is really a problem you need to address with your vendor.  If they won't or can't solve the performance problems via indexes, do you think that the vendor is going to support something like pureScale or Q-rep?